# Proof $ e^{x-1} \geq{x} $ by writting $e^x$ as a infinite series

Tags: real-analysis

By writing $e^x$ as a infinite series proof that for every $x\geq{0}$ is true:
$$ e^{x-1} \geq{x} $$
Also when is true $e^{x-1} = x$?

Comment: $e^x$ cannot be written as a sequence as far as I'm aware... do you mean an infinite series like $\exp x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$?

Comment: When is it true $e^{x-1} = x$. We see that $-e^{-1} = -xe^{-x}$.  We may invoke the Lambert W-function. $x = -W(-\frac{1}{e})$. WolframAlpha can evaluate that for you. The only result is $x=1$. Inspection will reveal this result, too.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Assuming you mean a series, the formula you are looking for is:

$$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Plug in $x-1$ to get $$e^{x-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(x-1)^n}{n!}$$

and look at the first few (in your case two) terms of the sequence.